# validate numeric field, value between 1 and 10

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Is it possible to validate numeric field, based on its numeral value? for example it should be bigger than 1 and smaller than 10.

I checked the [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html), but it has only `length` validation.

Comment: Validation::comparison or Validation::range in the same doc...

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom model rule
Like this

```
phoneno' => array(
    'rule' => array('isValidPhone')
),

 function isValidPhone($phone){
 $phone_no=$phone['phoneno'];
 $errors = array();
 if(empty($phone_no)) {
    $errors [] = "Please enter Phone Number";
 }
 else if (!preg_match ("/[^1-9]/", $phone_no);) {
    $errors [] = "Please enter valid Phone Number";
 } 

if (!empty($errors))
return implode("\n", $errors);

 return true;
```

}